# Why the hourglass icon is showing?

Tags: display, process

After an update of with 'rpi-update' command, while I am opening this menu ,I am noticing a sand-glass icon with the pointer.
This is not a very big problem. But I am confused ,what is happening??
Because, before the update, it was not happening.
Is it a problem that I should mind.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The screenshot does not include the mouse pointer. So we can't see what you are seeing.

Comment: Please don't ask here about weird results when using `rpi-update`. It's only made for testing latest software versions that are declared not to be stable. Tell it to the developers.